# convert standard date to standard persian date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, persian

I have a function that can convert the standard date to persian standard date as you can see here:

```
 public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime datetime)
        {
            PersianCalendar persian_date = new PersianCalendar();
            string date;
            string year = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(datetime));
            string Month = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(datetime));
            string day = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(datetime));

            date = year+"/" + Month + "/" + day;
            return date;
        }
```

But i have a problem with these outputs:

```
1394/5/1
1394/12/8
1395/7/12
```

These outputs should be like this :

```
1394/05/01
1394/12/08
1395/07/12
```

I can count the digit numbers of the day and month but i thing it isn't the best way to do that .could you please give me some help about how can i change these kind of outputs using `stringformat`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is add a leading zero.  `.ToString` can be used.

```
string Month = persian_date.GetMonth(datetime).ToString("D2");
string day = persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(datetime).ToString("D2");
```

Comment: you mean  return date.ToString();?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function:

```
private static string UpdateDate(string date)
{
    date.PadLeft(2, '0');
}

date = year+"/" + UpdateDate(Month) + "/" + UpdateDate(day);
```